# Intellisense not working while writing BIMLScript in SQL Server Business Intelligent Studio 2008(SSIS)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, biml

I have installed BIDSHelper to work on BIML. Intellisense is not working here. I tried looking into Tools/Options of BIDS but cannot find any way to resolve this.Can anyone provide some info on how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BIDSHelper does not support intellisense for scripting - only "flat" Biml. The moment you add scripting into the mix, the intellisense breaks.

BimlExpress while it does provide support for intellisense, is only available back to Visual Studio 2010 and I don't believe 2010 supported 2008/2008 R2.

You can try BimlScript.com or BimlOnline.com and see if you can work within the limitations there.

Comment: Thanks ! will check it out.